# Paypal adaptive payments blocking payment because of regulatory requirements

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've suddenly been getting this error since yesterday when paying multiple accounts: "Invalid request: We had to block this payment because it didn't comply with regulatory requirements".

This was working fine last week (and have been so for a long time) but started returning this error yesterday. I can't find any info about it and what needs to be done, can anyone help?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about computer programming and should be addressed to PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about the accounts involved and the full error message returned, it's only possible to guess that it might have to do with the country or currency of the accounts involved.

Contact PayPal for support